# strange SQLiteDatabase behaviour on android.. (contacts provider)

Tags: android, sqlite

I am experiencing strange behaviour with android's contacts provider..
this is my code:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.CONTENT_URI;
String[] columns = new String[]{ ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS };
String where = ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.PROTOCOL+"="+PROTOCOL_GOOGLE_TALK+
        " AND "+ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.IM_HANDLE+"='";
Cursor cursor = c.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, where+acc+'\'', null, null);
```

which leads to the following exception:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: protocol: , while compiling: SELECT status FROM view_data_restricted data LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                  status_updates ON(status_updates.status_update_data_id=data._id) WHERE (protocol=5 AND im_handle='xxx')

hower, when I change

```
String[] columns = new String[]{ ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS };
```

to

```
{ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.PRESENCE}
```

it works. :o

How can that be possible??